# C error: program is free of memory errors, valgrind tests failed

Tags: c, memory, valgrind, cs50

I am doing the [CS50 PSet 4 Recover problem](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/4/recover/) and get the below error:

```
program is free of memory errors
    valgrind tests failed; see log for more information.
```

I don't understand what is the error, and therefore not sure how to fix it. I've tried using the debugger but it doesn't help.

My code is the below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>


typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check number of arguments
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Only one argument should be used\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open reading file
    FILE *input_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (input_file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 2;
    }

    // Store blocks of 512 bytes in an array
    BYTE buffer[512];

    // Keep track of number of images generated
    int count_image = 0;

    // File pointer for recovered images
    FILE *output_file = NULL;

    // Char filename
    char *filename = malloc (8 * sizeof(char));

    // Read the blocks of 512 bytes
    while (fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 512, input_file))
    {
        // Check if the bytes indicate start of JPEG
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            // Write the JPEG filenames
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count_image);

            // Open output file for writing
            output_file = fopen(filename, "w");

            // Count number of images found
            count_image++;
        }

        if (output_file != NULL)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), 512, output_file);
        }
    }

    free(filename);
    fclose(output_file);
    fclose(input_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong? Valgrind says there's an error with the line:

```
output_file = fopen(filename, "w");
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. How many files do you open for writing? How many of them do you close?

Comment: Not related to the issue but there is no reason to use `malloc` for your filename. A simple array would also do it.

Comment: Think about how many times an output file is opened, and how many times it is closed.

Comment: "How many files do you open for writing? How many of them do you close?"

Good question. I am not sure. Let me tell you why.
I think I understood the problem and how the logic works, but some pieces I found online since I could not solve them.

I know that the program should find 50 JPEG images, which means it should open 50 times a file and close 50 times a file?

Comment: 50 + 50 would be good. But where in your code would you close 50 files? You open them in a loop but only close once after the loop. You must close the old file whenever you open a new one. Otherwise the pointer to the old `FILE` structure is lost and you can never close the file resulting in 49 memory leaks.

Comment: You're right, I stayed late last night to figure out my code and I added the below which fixes my leaks

// Close output file before writing a new one
            if (output_file != NULL)
            {
                fclose(output_file);
            }

Thank you so much for your prompt replies! This coding newbie appreciates it <3

Comment: To help future visitors with the same problem you should consider to post an own answer, and later mark it. You might want to take the [tour] and read some of the linked pages to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But where in your code would you close 50 files? You open them in a loop but only close once after the loop. You must close the old file whenever you open a new one. Otherwise the pointer to the old FILE structure is lost and you can never close the file resulting in 49 memory leaks.